# Can an entitlements file be specified when using -exportArchive with an unsigned archive?

Tags: ios, xcode

**tl;dr** Is there anyway to specify an arbitrary entitlements file when using `xcodebuild -exportArchive` to export a previously-unsigned xcarchive?

We build an *unsigned* xcarchive during our build phase (), with the intention of signing appropriately and exporting to an IPA (via `-exportArchive`) when releasing to Test/UAT/Store.

This works quite well, but I'm struggling to understand how to integrate an entitlements file into the process. All of the documentation/posts I can find either apply it at build time (`CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=X`, which is never mentioned in relation to `-exportArchive`) or when explicitly resigning the application binary (`codesign --entitlements`).

Furthermore, any clarification / documentation links on how entitlement signing works within the IPA would be appreciated (namely, how does the runtime know which entitlements file to use?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is the way of such things, I found something that works immediately after posting the question.

If you run `codesign --entitlements <entitlementsfile> -f -s <identity> <binary>` immediately before `xcodebuild -exportArchive`, the resulting IPA will have the correct entitlements.